# Bash: How to change select statement options input keys?

Tags: linux, bash, function, select, case

I am making a bash script with two case statements for creating a menu and its follow-up sub-menu.

My main menu is structured like this:
Here, any selection is redirected to the SubMenu function.

```
Main-menu() {
    select INPUT in "Apple" "Banana" "Kiwi" "Coconut" "Pasta" "Exit"
    do
        case $INPUT in
            "Apple") echo "You selected: $INPUT";SubMenu;;
            "Banana") echo "You selected: $INPUT";SubMenu;;
            "Kiwi") echo "You selected: $INPUT";SubMenu;;
            "Coconut") echo "You selected: $INPUT";SubMenu;;
            "Pasta") echo "You selected: $INPUT";SubMenu;;
            "Exit") echo "Goodbye..";exit;;
            *) echo -e "Please enter valid number";;
        esac
    done
}
```

My sub-menu is structured similarly:
Here, the selection is redirected to a function (FruitType,etc.).

```
SubMenu() {
echo "Which Category should this be under? Select from options below: [F,N,D,E]"
    select type in "Fruits" "Nuts" "Dinner" "Exit"
    do
        case $type in
            "Fruits") echo "You selected: $type";FruitType;;
            "Nuts") echo "You selected: $type";NutsType;;
            "Dinner") echo "You selected: $type";DinnerType;;
            "Exit") echo "Goodbye..";exit;;
            *) echo -e "Please enter a valid letter";;
        esac
    done
}
```

**
The question here is for my SubMenu. I need to have [F,N,D,E] as my options for my input but it displays numeric options [1,2,3,4]. **

I have seen some examples of OPTARG and options like this:

```
while getopts u:p: option; do
    case $option in
        u) user=$OPTARG;;
        p) pass=$OPTARG;;
    esac
done
```

But here, I have to enter -u instead of u as my input. Also the options aren't displayed. I need to have the SubMenu options displayed and a letter as input.

Any ideas?

Comment: Numbers are how `select` _works_. If you don't want what it does, don't use it; you're perfectly welcome to write a function that behaves the way you want instead. (Why use `getopts` and not just `read`?)

Comment: (and to be clear, this is a `select` problem, not a `case` problem as the title implies -- `case` doesn't have opinions about any of this).

Comment: Oh I see. What loop should I use with read?

Comment: `read -p 'Which Category should this be under? Select from options below: [F,N,D,E]' type; case $type in F|Fruit) ...;; N|Nuts) ...;; ... esac`

Comment: Also, thanks for noting, Ill edit the title

Comment: (to make that a loop, change it from `read -p` to `while read -p`, and `break` out of the loop when you don't need to repeat)

Comment: (maybe `case ${type^^} in F|FRUIT)` to make it case-insensitive with modern versions of bash: `${var^^}` converts the contents of `$var` to upper-case)

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried read -p and 'F|Fruit...' etc. with the while loop and case ${type^^}, it's working great. Please copy this as an answer so I can verify it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select` is hardcoded to use numbers, but you can just use `read -p` instead without it:

```
while read -r -p $'Which category should this be under?\nSelect from options: [F]ruit, [N]uts, [D]inner, [E]ggs -- or [Q]uit:' type
  case ${type^^} in
    F|FRUIT)  echo "You selected fruit";;
    N|NUTS)   echo "You selected nuts";;
    D|DINNER) echo "You selected dinner";;
    E|EGGS)   echo "You selected eggs";;
    Q|QUIT)   echo "Done with the loop"; break;;
    *)        echo "Invalid selection";;
  esac
done
```